# Add Kaliningrad Oblast to NUTS-2 EU map

Tags: r, maps, shapefile, r-sf

I am struggling to add the Kaliningrad Oblast to the EU NUTS-2 map, otherwise it looks like there is sea between Poland and Lithuania. I tried with different shp files, however each time I attempt to add the Russian dataset to the European one, I get a coordinate error.

Here my code:

- I downloaded the EU NUTS-2 shp file from: https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/nuts (File format: GeoJSON; Geometry Type: Polygons (RG); Scale: 20M; CRS: 4326);
- I downloaded the Russia shp file from: https://gadm.org/download_country.html (Shapefile)

  ```
  library(sf)
  library(tidyverse)

  nuts2 <- read_sf("D:/NUTS_RG_20M_2021_4326.geojson")

  russia<- read_sf("D:/gadm36_RUS_shp/gadm36_RUS_1.shp")
  russia<-rename(russia, c("CNTR_CODE"="GID_0"), c("NUTS_ID"="GID_1"))
  nuts_agg <- nuts2 %>% 
    filter(!CNTR_CODE %in% c( c( "TR"))) %>% 

   filter(!NUTS_ID %in% c( "ES70", "PT20", "PT30",
                           "FRY1", "FRY2","FRY3", "FRY4", "FRY5", "NO0B"))
  euru<-st_join(nuts_agg, russia, BY=c("CNTR_CODE", "NUTS_ID", "geometry"))
  ```

I also tried with different shp files, but each time I got a different error. The main problem is that the geometry of Russia is not being recognized.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: I have struggled with this as well! There are use cases when you don't want to show Russia in it's entirety, but you don't want a land gap around Königsberg. I ended up carving out a piece of Russia that fits a buffer around Bern. Have a look at https://www.jla-data.net/eng/breadbaskets-of-europe/ for a possible implementation with R code.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/ is a better avenue for this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see some things that would throw an error on your code:

- `rename(russia, c("CNTR_CODE"="GID_0"), c("NUTS_ID"="GID_1"))` is not working as you may expect.
- `st_join` is performing a **spatial join**, that would make a join based on the overlapping areas of the shapes, and what you want is really **append** the information.

I would use `giscoR` and `GADMtools` package, that are two API packages that extract the very same shapefiles that you use, in order to provide full reproducibility.

See a reprex here:

```r
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

# packages for downloading shapes
library(giscoR)
library(GADMTools)

# Same source than your example
nuts2 <- gisco_get_nuts(resolution = 20, year = 2021, epsg = 4326, nuts_level = 2)
names(nuts2)
#>  [1] "MOUNT_TYPE" "NAME_LATN"  "CNTR_CODE"  "NUTS_NAME"  "NUTS_ID"   
#>  [6] "LEVL_CODE"  "URBN_TYPE"  "COAST_TYPE" "FID"        "geometry"

# Same source than your example
russia <- gadm_sf.loadCountries("RUS", level = 1)

# Extract the sf object for Kaliningrad and align CRS with NUTS2
kalin_sf <- russia$sf %>%
  filter(NAME_1 == "Kaliningrad") %>%
  st_transform(st_crs(st_crs(nuts2)))
#> old-style crs object detected; please recreate object with a recent sf::st_crs()

# Adapt columns and make join
names(kalin_sf)
#> [1] "ISO"       "NAME_0"    "NAME_1"    "TYPE_1"    "ENGTYPE_1" "geometry"
kalin_sf <- kalin_sf %>%
  rename(
    CNTR_CODE = NAME_1,
    NUTS_ID = NAME_0
  )


# Now we can bind rows (NO SPATIAL JOIN!!) and perform filters

euru <- nuts2 %>%
  bind_rows(kalin_sf) %>%
  filter(
    CNTR_CODE != "TR",
    !NUTS_ID %in% c(
      "ES70", "PT20", "PT30",
      "FRY1", "FRY2", "FRY3", "FRY4", "FRY5", "NO0B"
    )
  )

# Plot
ggplot(euru) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = TYPE_1)) +
  # Represent on EPSG 3035, one of the official CRS of the European Union
  coord_sf(crs = 3035) +
  labs(title = "NUTS2 with Kaliningrad Oblast")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> - Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
#>  os       Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32
#>  ui       RTerm
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  Spanish_Spain.1252
#>  ctype    Spanish_Spain.1252
#>  tz       Europe/Paris
#>  date     2022-02-18
#>  pandoc   2.14.0.3 @ C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> - Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package     * version    date (UTC) lib source
#>  assertthat    0.2.1      2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  backports     1.4.1      2021-12-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  bitops        1.0-7      2021-04-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  broom         0.7.12     2022-01-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  cellranger    1.1.0      2016-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  class         7.3-19     2021-05-03 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  classInt    * 0.4-3      2020-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  cli           3.2.0      2022-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  colorspace    2.0-2      2021-06-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  crayon        1.5.0      2022-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  curl          4.3.2      2021-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  DBI           1.1.2      2021-12-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  dbplyr        2.1.1      2021-04-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  digest        0.6.29     2021-12-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  dplyr       * 1.0.8      2022-02-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  e1071         1.7-9      2021-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  ellipsis      0.3.2      2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  evaluate      0.14       2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  fansi         1.0.2      2022-01-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  farver        2.1.0      2021-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  fastmap       1.1.0      2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  forcats     * 0.5.1      2021-01-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  foreign       0.8-81     2020-12-22 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  fs            1.5.2      2021-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  GADMTools   * 3.9-1      2021-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  generics      0.1.2      2022-01-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  geojsonsf     2.0.1      2020-10-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  ggmap         3.0.0      2019-02-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  ggplot2     * 3.3.5      2021-06-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  ggspatial     1.1.5.9000 2022-01-24 [1] Github (paleolimbot/ggspatial@20a8708)
#>  giscoR      * 0.3.1      2021-10-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  glue          1.6.1      2022-01-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  gridExtra     2.3        2017-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  gtable        0.3.0      2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  haven         2.4.3      2021-08-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  highr         0.9        2021-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  hms           1.1.1      2021-09-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  htmltools     0.5.2      2021-08-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  httr          1.4.2      2020-07-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  jpeg          0.1-9      2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  jsonlite      1.7.3      2022-01-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  KernSmooth    2.23-20    2021-05-03 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  knitr         1.37       2021-12-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  lattice       0.20-45    2021-09-22 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  lifecycle     1.0.1      2021-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  lubridate     1.8.0      2021-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  magrittr      2.0.2      2022-01-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  maptools      1.1-2      2021-09-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  mime          0.12       2021-09-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  modelr        0.1.8      2020-05-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  munsell       0.5.0      2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  pillar        1.7.0      2022-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  pkgconfig     2.0.3      2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  plyr          1.8.6      2020-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  png           0.1-7      2013-12-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  proxy         0.4-26     2021-06-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  purrr       * 0.3.4      2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  R.cache       0.15.0     2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  R.methodsS3   1.8.1      2020-08-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  R.oo          1.24.0     2020-08-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  R.utils       2.11.0     2021-09-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  R6            2.5.1      2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  Rcpp          1.0.8      2022-01-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  readr       * 2.1.2      2022-01-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  readxl        1.3.1      2019-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  reprex        2.0.1      2021-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  rgdal       * 1.5-28     2021-12-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  rgeos         0.5-9      2021-12-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  RgoogleMaps   1.4.5.3    2020-02-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  rjson         0.2.21     2022-01-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  rlang         1.0.1      2022-02-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  rmarkdown     2.11       2021-09-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  rosm          0.2.5      2019-07-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  rstudioapi    0.13       2020-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  rvest         1.0.2      2021-10-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  s2            1.0.7      2021-09-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  scales        1.1.1      2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  sessioninfo   1.2.2      2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  sf          * 1.0-6      2022-02-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  sp          * 1.4-6      2021-11-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  stringi       1.7.6      2021-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  stringr     * 1.4.0      2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  styler        1.6.2      2021-09-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  tibble      * 3.1.6      2021-11-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  tidyr       * 1.2.0      2022-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  tidyselect    1.1.1      2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  tidyverse   * 1.3.1      2021-04-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  tzdb          0.2.0      2021-10-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  units         0.8-0      2022-02-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  utf8          1.2.2      2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  vctrs         0.3.8      2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  withr         2.4.3      2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  wk            0.6.0      2022-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  xfun          0.29       2021-12-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  xml2          1.3.3      2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  yaml          2.2.2      2022-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#> 
#>  [1] C:/Users/diego/Documents/R/win-library/4.1
#>  [2] C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library
#> 
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```